# Why passing JSON parameters from HTML to Node.js results in body parameter is undefined

Tags: node.js, json, html-post

I'm playing with Node.js for the first time trying to pass parameters from a form to my server and print them on the console

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Hello Node</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1> we have a website</h1>
    <form action="/contact" enctype="application/json" method="POST">
        <input name="firstName" placeholder="firstName" type="text" size="30" />
        <input name="lastName" placeholder="lastName" type="text" size="30" />
    
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send This">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

- i've tried both with and without `enctype="application/json"`

my app.js file

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') 
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log("Server is up and listening on 3003"); //print to the server console (the terminal!!)
})

app.post("/contact", jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log("in /contact");
  console.log("request body:" + req.body);
  console.log("request body first name:" + req.body.firstName);
  console.log("request query first name:" + req.query.firstName);
})
```

- I've tried with and without `app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))`

**Output:**

[object Object]

request body first name:undefined

request query first name:undefined

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) `application/json` content type is not allowed to be set as enctype value, so you can either send json using javascript or add support for application/x-www-form-urlencoded via `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

Comment: bodyParser.urlencoded -- I thought i need to use this when I'm passing parameters in the URL string i.e: /contact/?firstname:"kukula"